Можно ли большой список команд в package.json вынести в другой файл?
есть большой список команд в файле package.json
Можно ли его вынести в другие файлы?

Ну... можно коннечно.

@"чистов_n" а можно подробнее - как это сделать?

А у вас в вопросе написано "Можно ли?". Я и ответил. Вы вопрос переделайте.

https://qna.habr.com/q/1241760
